# Android: How can i logout of Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook

I am using this Code to get User details and use them as credentials to login to my server:

```
public class FacebookDialog extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("211111915613509");
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!(getSharedPreferences(SplashActivity.USER_PREFS, 0).getBoolean(
                "fb", false))) {

            try {
                String s = facebook.logout(this);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        }
        /*
         * Get existing access_token if any
         */
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires",
                            facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    getFbDetails();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });
        } else {
            getFbDetails();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
    }
}
```

This works fine.

I am setting **fb** as **true** when user logs in using Facebook and **false** when user clicks logout in my app.

The problem is:

when i logout and again try to login using facebook (I am even logged out on Facebook application). I could still get the user details.

Where am i doing wrong?

I am using facebook.logout() by checking if **fb** is false.

I believe session is not being cleared, how to do that?

Thank You

Comment: First of all   After Facebook authenticate returning into onComplete(), U dont need to use SharedPreference to store those values. because you are calling getFbDetails(); and you must have got all data you are looking for. And check for the Context you are passing at the time of Logout. Because Context should be the same  which was at the time logIn. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on logout button try this:-

```
         mFacebook.authorize(PlayVideo.this, new String[] {}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new LogoutDialogListener());}

 public final class LogoutDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        try {

            // SessionStore.clear(Login.mFacebook, PlayVideo.this);
            Util.clearCookies(PlayVideo.this);

            Login.mFacebook.setAccessToken(null);
            Login.mFacebook.setAccessExpires(0);
            return;

        } catch (Exception error) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayVideo.this, error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayVideo.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayVideo.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(PlayVideo.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So using **Util.clearCookies(Context c);** after **facebook.logout();** will solve the problem??

Comment: I think Yes bcz its working for me. Its my complete logout code.

Comment: I added the code from your onComplete method after facebook.logout(); But it still gives me the user data

Comment: Try this- by adding two line also mFacebook.setAccessToken(null);
mFacebook.setAccessExpires(0);& if this is in sharedPreference then try something this:-Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.clear();editor.commit();

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can edit the FbDialog.java in the Facebook SDK (this is not the latest one that just came out a couple of weeks ago, but the previous one).

I just pulled this out of my code which I had altered a long time ago. I believe the password line is the one that does the trick (starting around line 109)...

```
private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FbDialog.FbWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebSettings.setSavePassword(false); //RIGHT HERE
        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }
```

That will prevent your login from persisting.

Comment: There is no such method in latest SDK